# How to preserve constant segments in the signal during digital filtering

Tags: digital-filters

I have a sampled signal, which has constant segments(I pad the signal if some of the BLE packets were lost). I want to apply a digital filter to the signal, say Butterworth and I don't want it to affect the constant segments. Any advice how to achieve it? An example of such filtering I see in EDF browser, but I it's hard for me to go into its implementation.